# Coded Webtests in Visual Studio: Testing first link on page

Tags: visual-studio, testing

I'm using visual studio's web testing capabilities. I've recorded a web test and converted it to a coded web test.

I'd like to test the first link on the page (well, in a section of the page, but for discussion's sake let's say the first link).

For example, let's say that I have a div on my page that has links to the 3 most recent posts.  When recording the web test, and I click on the first link, what's recorded is the request to that post. I'd like to test that the "3 most recent posts" function is working properly when I run my test later. The way it's currently being recorded will just test if a request to the particular post that I clicked on works.

In the coded web test, can I build a request by getting an element by id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It's using Validation and Extraction rules.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243183.aspx
- bb385904.aspx (I don't have enough reputation points yet to post more than one link ;-) )

You can do this either before or after you convert a webtest to a coded web test.